# How do I change the import file?

Tags: go

I have the following function in golang:

```
import (
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/iam"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
    "fmt"
)
func NewIAM() *SphinxIAM {
//  awsConfig := aws.NewConfig()
    sess, err := session.NewSession()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Failed to create session,", err)
        return nil
    }
    session := &SphinxIAM{iam: iam.New(sess)}
    return session
}
```

Now, I am getting the following error when I run this:

```
cannot use sess (type *session.Session) as type "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/client".ConfigProvider in argument to iam.New:
    *session.Session does not implement "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/client".ConfigProvider (wrong type for ClientConfig method)
        have ClientConfig(string, ...*"stash/cloud/sphinx/vendor/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws".Config) "stash/cloud/sphinx/vendor/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/client".Config
        want ClientConfig(string, ...*"github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws".Config) "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/client".Config
```

I have to change the method getting imported but how do I exactly do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that your `github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session` package is *vendored*, it is loaded from the folder `stash/cloud/sphinx/vendor/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws`.

But the function you want to pass it: `iam.New()` is not vendored, it does not come from the same vendor folder (`stash/cloud/sphinx/vendor/xxx`) but it comes directly from `github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/iam`.

Either put both packages under the same vendor folder, or none. It is possible that one of your dependency tool does this, (e.g. `glide`), in which case you should instruct your tool to handle both as vendored.